# Carregar uma imagem ao abrir o aplicativo em Android

Tags: java, android

Preciso que no momento em que abro meu aplicativo Android carregue a logomarca e depois apareça o *Home*.

Alguém tem o código como fazer?

Answer (score 2):

O que realmente você se refere é a tela de apresentação, ou *splash screen*, é a tela inicial que é exibida ao abrir uma aplicação. A maioria dos aplicativos apresentam a *splash screens* geralmente para exibir o logo da aplicação ou até mesmo a logomarca da própria empresa desenvolvedora. Também pode ser uma maneira de "distrair" o usuário durante alguns segundos enquanto a aplicação realiza algum processo ou carregamento inicial de banco de dados, etc.

Não existe complexidade em criar um *splash screen*. Pode ser feito de diferentes maneiras possíveis. Um exemplo usar-se de preferência uma `Activity` para o *Splash* que implementa a classe *[Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html)*. Assim, é usado o método `run` para iniciar a primeira `Activity` após a apresentação. Veja abaixo um exemplo simples de implementação:

**SplashScreen.class**

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
         // define o tempo de execução em 3 segundos
        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
    }

    public void run(){
        // inicia outra activity após o termino do tempo
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

**splash.xml**

No método `setContentView` é preciso incluir seu `splash.xml`. Veja

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/imagem"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

No seu `AndroidManifest.xml` é preciso incluir sua Activity para que seja invocada ao iniciar a aplicação. Veja:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_laucher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">

  <activity android:name="SplashScreen" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <activity android:name="ActivityMain" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```